# bootstrap-dialog library using bootstrap 5

Tags: bootstrap-5, bootstrap-dialog

I would like to use this library:
https://github.com/GedMarc/bootstrap4-dialog

It says it supports bootstrap 5, but I could not figure out how to make it work with bootstrap 5 (in this example u can see that I used bootstrap 4).

```js
BootstrapDialog.show({
    title: 'Example',
    message: 'Write your example here.',
    buttons: [{
        label: 'Close',
        action: function(dialog) {
            dialog.close();
        }
    }]
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/GedMarc/bootstrap4-dialog/dist/css/bootstrap-dialog.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/GedMarc/bootstrap4-dialog/dist/js/bootstrap-dialog.js"></script>

<!--
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
-->
```

Comment: what is the expected outcome? It seems to create a dialog popup fine.

Comment: it uses bootstrap 4 and not 5.